# Axios default configuration - how to set baseUrl and header correctly?

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to set configure the axios with baseUrl and headers for each call. Is the following code correct? If I set configuration for axios this way, will this be passed on each call to the API (regardless of the method)?

```
const token = "blablabal";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: `https://api-sandbox.bank.com`,
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer" + token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "User-Agent": "Name",
  },
});
```

Many Thanks

Comment: That looks OK, it looks like you are missing a space after "Bearer ", otherwise looks good. I am not sure this question fits the SO standards though, you may want to have a look at [ask] to make sure.

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: I will check How to Ask guide and thanks for the answer!